# Take the last record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a table like:

```
Create table Accounts
(
  account_key char(2)
 ,account_name varchar(1024)
 ,type varchar(50)
 ,date_entered date
);
```

I need to select each `account_name` with the latest record. How this can be done? Desirable through `Row_Number`

Comment: Did you try anything using `ROW_NUMBER` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT account_key, account_name, type, date_entered,
         rn = row_number() over (partition by account_name order by date_entered desc)
  FROM dbo.Accounts
)
SELECT account_key, account_name, type, date_entered
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like:**

```
SELECT account_key, account_name, type, date_entered
from (
       SELECT account_key,account_name,type,date_entered,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_entered DESC) AS RN
       FROM Accounts  
                      )   X 
WHERE X.RN=1
```